# PHP PDO connect to MS SQLServer Express using SSL

Tags: php, sql-server, ssl, pdo

I have a remote MS-SQL Express 2012 server that is set up for use with SSL. I have all the certs I need. But how can I create a PDO connection to this server using SSL? I have found plenty of articles for PDO with MySQL using SSL, but none for MS-SQL using PDO and SSL.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We set up a VPN and use a non-SSL connection.

Comment: did you try like this : $c = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=12345abcde.database.windows.net;Database=bddtest", "Utilisateur@12345abcde", "MotDePasse");    ?

Answer (score 0):

(Microsoft OS Only) In order to connect securely, append 'encrypt=true' to the connection string.
A valuable [blog on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/03/08/sql-server-driver-for-php-connection-options-encrypt.aspx).

Also Of Note:

Make sure you are using:

- [Microsoft Drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)

Make sure you aren't using:

- [Outdated](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)
- [Wrong Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php)

The drivers are located here: [Microsoft provided drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

Comment: Unfortunately that driver only works on Windows. My web servers all run Linux.

Comment: You might be able to use FreeTDS.  I am unable to test and verify - but that is the only way I'm aware of in Linux. (it might even use SSL for domain auth connections by default).