# Connect to MSSQL server via PHP PDO over SSL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, ssl, pdo

I have a working connection to an MSSQL server via PHP PDO.

```
$mssql = new PDO('dblib:host=1.2.3.4;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');
```

I now need this connection to be secure, sending all transactions over SSL. I do not see [any references to secure connections in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) for the DBLIB driver.

Can someone provide some insight on how I might enable this connection over SSL? (I have the ability to export and import certificates across both servers, if needed.)

**EDIT:** I'm on PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: Any resolution to this?  Added a tag (`sql-server`). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9768753/1816093

Comment: $mssql = new PDO('dblib:host=1.2.3.4;dbname=databasename;Encrypt=1', 'username', 'password'); per http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Comment: wups, that's if you're using PDO_SQLSRV , not PDO_DBLIB ... try changing the driver? PDO_SQLSRV is documented to support ssl and MSSQL :/

Comment: not sure if this is answering your query

visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738712/connect-to-remote-mysql-server-with-ssl-from-php

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294221/php-pdo-connect-to-ms-sqlserver-express-using-ssl/33322487#33322487)

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309615/connect-to-a-mysql-server-over-ssh-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on your server setup, but the 'official' way to do this is with the Microsoft's  [drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff657782.aspx). Unfortunately, they only work with SSL for Windows PHP servers.  Here are the  [connection options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167(v=sql.105).aspx).

If you are on Linux, there is one option that does SSL, but it isn't officially MS supported.

Answer (score 0):

I know its abit late to post this out as its 6 years later, but currently ive got this solution using PDO with mssql. However i am using ODBC with MSSQL, this is what i did to get the PDO working with XAMPP as localhost

Apparently, odbc&mssql does not require complicated like this

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
```

but just simple

```
$conn = new PDO ("odbc:$dbname", $username, $password);
```

**This is the working code for my sysyem**

```
 $dbname = "Form_Database";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";

    try{
        $conn = new PDO ("odbc:$dbname", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("<--SQL QUERY-->");
        $stmt -> execute();
        $result = $stmt -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```